# pyserial read only what was written

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to write a python script to read data from a domotic regulator, which uses serial port to communicate.
I use this shell command from my raspberry py:

```
cu -l /dev/ttyUSB1 -s 115200
```

and then I am able to pass some commands and read the answers fine. 
example:

```
si>test_showw
```

get this answer:

```
Raw values of OTS2/RTS/PDS/SRS:
0xffffffff/0x0000780f/0xffffffff/0xffffffff
Converted values of OTS2/RTS/PDS/SRS:
-99.0/21.2/0/-99.0
RSSI (dBm) values of OTS2/RTS/PDS/SRS:
-255/-67/-255/-255
Seconds since last telegram of OTS2/RTS/PDS/SRS:
5091450/4/5091450/5091450
```

if command is not known, regulator answer:

```
Unknown command...
```

Answer are usually up to 200 char long. 
So I have tried to run following code from my raspberry:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=115200, timeout=0)
ser.write('test_showw'.encode('utf-8')) #ser.write(b'test_showw')
s = ser.readline() #ser.read(), ser.read(10), ser.read(size=10)
print(s)
ser.close()
```

But All I can get with read function is 'test_showw', the command I have written to the port.
I have read common issue and tried timeout with 0,1,2,None values and read with different signatures, but result remains identical. The read-buffer contains only what I sent in write function

PS: I actually found a  shell that succeed to retrieve datas, which is here.

```
...
system "stty 115200 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke < $dev"

spawn -open [ open $dev r+ ]
send "login $password\r"

expect {
  -re "Login OK\r\n(by|si|man)>" { send "$command\r" }
  -re "Login DENIED*" { exit 1 }
  timeout {
    puts "\nTimeout"
    close
    exit 1
  }
}
...
```

Apparently, a login is involved. I know $password, $dev and $command ('showw' in this case), but I have issue translating this into python. I can't understand how 'expect' and 'spawn' commands work.

Comment: Not understand your issue, the program just works, you write `test_showw`, and the board echo back it, what's wrong?

Comment: Hi Iagom, I have completed my explanation with an example of communication